# How to capture the Jquery Collapsable click event in this case?

Tags: jquery

I have Jquery `data-role="collapsible"` this way

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content oms-content">
    <div class="myactivelabelsWrap" id="result">
        <div data-role="collapsible" class="my-collaspible" data-inset="false" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-themed-content">
             <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading"><a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inherit ui-icon-minus">Haii <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon ui-link"></a><span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to collapse contents</span></a></h3>

            <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit" aria-hidden="false"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-a ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Create New Label</button>
    </div>
</div>

$('.my-collaspible').on('collapsibleexpand', function () {
    alert('Expanded');
});

$('.my-collaspible').on('collapsiblecollapse', function () {
    alert('Collapsed');
});
```

Could you please let me know how to capture the Collapsable click event for this ??

This is my jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/znz17ctm/3/

(I am constructing this HTML dynamically through JS , so i guess i should use events `$(document).on`  but not sure).

Answer (score 0):

I changed you code up a bit. The document.ready fixed what you have posted right now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.my-collaspible').on('collapsibleexpand', function () {
        alert('Expanded');

    });

    $('.my-collaspible').on('collapsiblecollapse', function()
    {
        alert('Collapsed');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/znz17ctm/4/

Comment: I posted a jsfiddle that catches both the events. Im not sure what you changed but mine seems to work.

Comment: Its not about the id and class , please see this fiddle , the event is not getting fired when selected the No Wrap Option . and i have kepe the same under ready also , but its not working .

Comment: Please see this fiddle e jsfiddle.net/znz17ctm/3

Comment: In your fiddle if i select the No Wrap Head Option under fiddle drop down its not getting fired .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/znz17ctm/5/ Wrapped you code in a document.ready and it works now.